# Firebase Firestore update time field security issue

Tags: firebase, web, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing a simple chat website using Firebase Firestore. And it obvious to store the message time .

Now the thing is that document is added from client side. So malcius user can add document with fake time. Is there any way avoid the scenario.

I have tried using cloud functions but it's taking too long lo send message..

Answer (score 3):

You want to set the message time property to equal Firebase Server timestamp which on submit will set it on the creation of the message using request.time you can validate it equals now.

**Security Rules**

```
allow create: if request.resource.data.messageTime == request.time && 
              // other rules for the message body
```

**Client side JS code**

```
const message = {
    text: 'Hello',
    messageTime: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
}
```